# Updating/editing username in dropdown list in react

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone help me.I have been trying to learn react for while now. How do I edit/update username in react dropdown list. Lets say there is a misspelled username in the dropdown list. If I want to change or edit that username how can I do that in react. I can update everything else, except the username. Here is my code..

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'


class EditExercise extends Component {
     constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDescription = this.onChangeDescription.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDuration = this.onChangeDuration.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDate = this.onChangeDate.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.select = React.createRef();

        this.state = {
                 username:'',
                 description : '',
                 duration: 0,
                 date:new Date(),
                 users: []
             }
         }
    
   componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/exercises/'+this.props.match.params.id)
            .then(responce => {
                this.setState({
                    username: responce.data.username,
                    description: responce.data.description,
                    duration:responce.data.duration,
                    date: new Date(responce.data.date)
                })
            })
            .catch((error) =>{
                console.log(error)
            })


        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/exercises/')   
            .then(responce => {
                if(responce.data.length > 0){
                    this.setState({
                        users: responce.data.map(user =>user.username),
                        
                    });
                }
            })
    }
    
    onChangeUsername(e){
        this.setState({
            username: e.target.value
        }); 
    }

    onChangeDescription(e){
         this.setState({
            description: e.target.value
        }); 
    } 

    onChangeDuration(e){
        this.setState({
            duration: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeDate(date){
        this.setState({
            date: date
        })
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const exercise  = { 
            username : this.state.username,
            description: this.state.description,
            duration: this.state.duration,
            date: this.state.date
        }

        console.log(exercise);

        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/exercises/update/'+this.props.match.params.id, exercise)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));

        window.location ='/';
    }

    
    render() { 
        return (  
            <div>
                <h3>Edit Exercise Log</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Username: </label>
                        <select ref={this.select}
                                required
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.username}
                                onChange={this.onChangeUsername}>
                                { 
                                    this.state.users.map((user) => {
                                        return <option 
                                        key={user}
                                        value={user}>{user}
                                        </option>
                                    })
                                }
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Description: </label>
                        <input  type="text"
                                required
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.description}
                                onChange={this.onChangeDescription}
                                />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Duration (in minutes): </label>
                        <input  type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.duration}
                                onChange={this.onChangeDuration}
                                />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Date: </label>
                        <div>
                            <DatePicker
                                selected={this.state.date}
                                onChange={this.onChangeDate}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Edit Exercise Log" className="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default EditExercise;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I see that you have a dropdown list of users that is coming from an API call. I am not entirely sure what you mean by edit the name. If the names are coming from an API and you want a user to select from a list of usernames you would need to add another JSX Input component with type text just like you do with your other fields.

My suggestion would be to add an edit icon next to the dropdown menu that onClick will setState={editUsername: true, editableUserName: this.state.username}.

This will trigger a ternary operator that renders your new component to the page (see below) below the current username Dropdown menu:

Example:

```js
{ this.state.editUsername ?
<div className="form-group">
    <label>Edit Username: </label>
        <input  type="text"
            required
            className="form-control"
            value={this.state.editableUserName}
            onChange={this.onUpdateUsername}
        />

    <button onClick="updateUsernameInDB()">
        Save Username
    </button>

</div>
: null
}
```

onUpdateUsername will need to update another state variable called editableUserName. Then when the user clicks save call the API that can edit the username of the user. One issue here is you will need some unique identifier for your username that you are updating or you can take the easier approach by sending the original username and the new username and update it that way although that is not the most sustainable over time. Then, when the API to update the username returns 200 you should setState={editUsername: false, updatedUsername: ''}

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks alot for quick replay

Comment: When I did the "editableUserName: this.state.username", its giving me cannot read property "username" of undefined. When I try it without the state like "this.username" I can only change the name of the first name in the list..

Comment: If you are setting the username in the state in the constructor like you showed above then this.state.username should be available to you. This error means that state is not defined which hints at a larger problem such as not creating the function inside the class EditExercise.